# What was Claire Temple's first strike?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, daredevil-tv

In Daredevil s02e11, Claire Temple  is said to keep her head down because it's her second strike. But when did her first strike happen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe they are referring to when she left work in Jessica Jones S1E13 to care for Luke Cage.